# Read 'Time without time zone' type as String(Character varying) type in PostgreSQL query

Tags: java, postgresql, time, timezone, hql

I have the following HQL query in java

```
try (Session context = HibernateUtil.getLocalSessionFactory().openSession()) {
    List list = null;
    String queryText = "select rf.Name, to_char(rf.StartDateTime,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), rf.Duration from RecordFile as rf";
    var query = context.createQuery(queryText);
    list = query.list();
}
var query = context.createQuery(queryText.toString());
```

The types are:

```
rf.Name -> Character varying (20),
rf.StartDateTime -> Timestamp without time zone,
rf.Duration -> Time without time zone
```

I need to read each of the three fields as string.
Name is String. StartDateTime converts to String by to_char method. But I couldn't convert the duration field to String. Duration is displaying in DB as like as 00:05:08, i.e. 00 hour and 05 mins and 08 secs.

Does anyone knows about that?

Thank

**Update**

In fact there is a class like

```
public MyClass
{
    MyClass(String name, String startDateTime, String Duration)
     {
       .
       .
       .
     }
}
```

which the query output invokes this class. that's why I need to convert Date to String and I'm not allowed to alter the DB.

The main queryText is:

```
String queryText = "select new PackageName.MyClass(rf.Name, to_char(rf.StartDateTime,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), rf.Duration) from RecordFile as rf";
```

Comment: Why do you want to retrieve the data as string?? Prefer to fetch a `timestamp without time zone` into a `LocalDateTime` and a `time without time zone` into a `LocalTime` (the latter is a bit dubious, we would prefer `Duration` in this case, but Hibernate may not support that).

Comment: Oh dear, retrieving strings from the database and handling date and time as strings in your Java model. Someone in your organization does not like to make things easy. :-( Are you also storing numbers and Boolean values in strings? ;-)

Comment: @OleV.V. Well, it may make sense if date/time handling & processing is taking place in the DB and not in the Java model. Maybe the latter just handles presentation. They _do_ store date/time and duration in the (almost) right native types.

Comment: It is an old project and The story is too complicated. We use the output as a web service response in C# side and not java model :(. For example the dateTime as a string transfers to C# and by DateTime.Parse(string-datetime-value) will converted to DateTime type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query literal to use `to_char`.

```sql
select rf.Name, to_char(rf.StartDateTime,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), 
       to_char(rf.Duration, 'HH24:MI:SS') as duration
from RecordFile as rf;
```

If you want to keep the fraction part then just

```sql
select rf.Name, to_char(rf.StartDateTime,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), 
       rf.Duration::text
from RecordFile as rf;
```

Not related, but I do not think that `time` is the right data type for a duration. Maybe use `interval`?

Comment: Your right, but unfortunately I'm not allowed to modify the DB. 
I'll check your solution. Thanks

Comment: The first suggestion has worked for me, but not second one. Thanks

Comment: "but not second one" - probably because of HQL interpretation of ':' as parameter token. Accept the answer?

Comment: Sure. You're right. Thanks